# Unexpected attribute "BuildInParallel" on element <msbuild>

Tags: msbuild, nant, nantcontrib

I am trying to use the BuildInParallel option on MsBuild.

I have an NAnt & NAntContrib script e.g.

```
<project xmlns="http://nant.sf.net/release/0.90/nant.xsd" name="Css Manager Solution Build" ToolsVersion="3.5" default="deploy">

        <target name="clean" description="Delete all previously compiled binaries.">
            <delete>
                <fileset>
                    <include name="**/bin/**" />
                    <include name="**/obj/**" />
                    <include name="**/*.suo" />
                    <include name="**/*.user" />
                </fileset>
            </delete>
        </target>

      <target name="deploy" description="Build and deploy all targets.">
            <msbuild project="CssManager.sln" BuildInParallel="true">
                <property name="Configuration" value="${configuration}"/>
                <property name="OutDir" value="${bin.output.dir}"/>
            </msbuild>
      </target>

</project>
```

but I get this error message:

```
Unexpected attribute "BuildInParallel" on element <msbuild>
```

Please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MSBuild` task of nant-contrib doesn't have a `BuildInParallel` attribute. You'll have to use the `Maxcpucount` command line argument.

```
<target name="deploy" description="Build and deploy all targets.">
  <msbuild project="CssManager.sln" BuildInParallel="true">
    <property name="Configuration" value="${configuration}"/>
    <property name="OutDir" value="${bin.output.dir}"/>
    <arg value="/maxcpucount:${environment::get-variable('NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS')}"/>
  </msbuild>
</target>
```

- [*More info on MaxCpuCount*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651793.aspx)
- [*More info on msbuild task*](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc4/help/tasks/msbuild.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I get this message: <msbuild> does not support the nested build element "args".

Comment: I am using NAntContrib version 0.85.2479

Comment: Thanks - My bad also - I checked the documentation but totally missed it.

Comment: As a side note, you can get the max by adding this: ${environment::get-variable('NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS')}